# Kivy Screen Manager Background Color

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and I am just learning to build a simple with a couple of screens. I saw the Kivy Crash Course videos and came up with the following code:

The Python file looks like this (main.py):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class sivaLoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(sivaLoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(253,253,152,1)

class sivaTabbedScreen(Screen):
    pass


class sivaScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# Tell Kivy to directly load a file. If this file defines a root widget, it will be returned by the method.
root_widget = Builder.load_file('siva.kv')

class sivaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Initialize root widget
                return root_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run application
    sivaApp().run()
```

The kv file looks something like this (siva.kv):

```
sivaScreenManager:
    sivaLoginScreen:


<sivaLoginScreen>:
    name: 'login_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 253, 253, 152, 1
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                id: login_label
                pos: 100, 100
                text: 'S.I.V.A'
                font_size: '20sp'
```

When I run the app with `python3 main.py` I get a black blank screen.
I was expecting a colored screen with a label on top of it. Can you please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only setup a color leaving the shape behind, so i've added that on this line.

```
<sivaLoginScreen>:
    name: 'login_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 253, 253, 152, 1
        Rectangle:
             pos:self.pos 
             size:self.size
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That really helped. One small question. The colour is set in rgba format both inside the kv file as well as in the Python code when the canvas is initialised. Does it have to be set twice or can I remove any one?

Comment: it's better you set canvas color through kv file only.. use python only if you MUST. so remove the python's own